# Setting Up Fail2Ban

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I am new to fail2ban. I want to setup Fail2Ban such that it bans an IP for one hour on two failed login attempts. I have the following setup:

```
/etc/fail2ban/jail.local.conf

[DEFAULT]
bantime = 3600
maxretry = 2
backend = systemd
usedns = warn
mode = normal
destemail = <MYEMAIL>
sender = <MYSENDER>
protocol = tcp
chain = <known/chain>
port = 0:65535
fail2ban_agent = Fail2Ban/%(fail2ban_version)s
...
# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with
# the interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section
action = %(action_mw)s

[sshd]

# To use more aggressive sshd modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
# normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all).
# See "tests/files/logs/sshd" or "filter.d/sshd.conf" for usage example and details.
#mode   = normal
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s


[dropbear]

port     = ssh
logpath  = %(dropbear_log)s
backend  = %(dropbear_backend)s


[selinux-ssh]

port     = ssh
logpath  = %(auditd_log)s
```

On `systemctl status fail2ban.service` I see the service is up. My assumption is it is using the jail.local.conf file. There are no errors reported. I don't have `iptables` installed. Is that necessary? If so, how do I set it up with my existing fail2ban setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess better later than never, so I'll post an answer to this, if anyone stumbles upon it like I did.

### Do you need iptables?

Basically, **Yes**, you need **iptables**. At least for fail2ban to work properly.

Simply use the `apt-get install iptables` to make that happen.

---

### How to setup your fail2ban jails?

Now to the first question.

Basically to setup your fail2ban to run properly (after installing it properly), you need to make a copy of the file `jail.conf` and edit that file.
Then reload the service to have it run according to your setup.

I'm detailing that below, but first: install fail2ban.

1. Copy of the `jail.conf` file:

```
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

2. Now that you have the copy, make the edits you want, then save the edits and exit the file.

```
nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

> You could add your own IP to prevent locking yourself out for example.
>  For that, find the `[DEFAULT]` row, below that, find the row that starts with `#ignoreip`, uncomment it, and paste your IPs (separated by a space).

3. You're all set now, you just need to restart fail2ban. For that just use the following command.

```
service fail2ban restart
```

> You can check the status of your jails with the following command:
> `fail2ban-client status sshd`

Comment: It's not necessary and usually considered bad practice to copy the jail.conf file. Just make your desired changes in an otherwise empty jail.local file.

Answer (score 2):

Your file has the wrong name. fail2ban will read a file named `jail.local`, not `jail.local.conf`. Rename the file and restart fail2ban.

Comment: Well that works too :) I should probably have read the first row of the setup properly! So this is actually the simplest reply to the question indeed! Thank you Michael!